# Toggle UISwitch as BarButtonItem

Tags: swift

I have a switch as a bar button but I am not sure how to reference the on/off value for a bar button item. XCode does not allow for the switch to be recognized as anything else except a bar button item. The switch is embedded in the barbutton and unable to be referenced.

```
@IBOutlet weak var toggleOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBAction func toggleButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

   // if toggleOutlet.on // not recognized as bar button item
```

if anyone could help that would be great 
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for your query.

You can do this using the following steps.

In view did load, call *setRightNavButton()* and do the addition task as,

---

### **Updated to Swift 4.1 :**

```
func audioSwitch(){
    let switchControl = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)))
    switchControl.isOn = true
    switchControl.onTintColor = UIColor.white
    switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false)
    switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchValueDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: switchControl)
}

@objc func switchValueDidChange(sender: UISwitch!)
{
    if sender.isOn {
        print("on")
    } else{
        print("off")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this in Swift 4.1 like :**

```
func rightNavButton(){

    let frameSize = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 30))
    let customSwitch = UISwitch(frame: frameSize)

    customSwitch.isOn = true
    customSwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.white
    customSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)

    customSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.switchTarget(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: customSwitch)
}


@objc func switchTarget(sender: UISwitch!)
{
    if sender.isOn {
        // do something ..
    } else{
        // do something ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting closer .. but function is not being recognized ;[

```
@IBAction func togglePresence(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    updateSwitch()
}

// hold empty status of switch
// this is set to true during viewDidLoad
var statusofswitch:Bool!

func updateSwitch() {
    if statusofswitch == true {
        statusofswitch = false
    }
    if statusofswitch == false {
        statusofswitch = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Toggle UISwitch with more buttons** as BarButtonItem in **Swift 4**

```
let switchControl = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:35, height:35))        
switchControl.onTintColor = UIColor.red
switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false)
switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTapped(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

let someImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")!
let someButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: someImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(someButtonTapped(sender:)))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: switchControl),someButton]
```

Action

```
@objc func switchTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {}
@objc func someButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {}
```